# Can I also create new tables or edit table structures with ADOdb?

Tags: php, database, adodb

Does anyone know if this is possible when I use ADOdb? I need to create new tables and edit table structures programmatically (i.e. adding new columns or modifying existing columns). I'm going to use MySQL for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think ADOdb has built-in methods to do this, but you can just run the appropriate SQL commands (ALTER TABLE, etc).